# Help doing unit testing using Rhino Mock

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks

How do i unit test the following class using Rhino Mocks

```cs
public interface IXmlTransformer
{
    void Transform(Stream inputXml, Stream transformedXml);
}

public class XmlToFOTransformer : IXmlTransformer
    {
        private string styleSheetPath = string.Empty;
        private bool fillable = true;

        public XmlToFOTransformer(
                                  string styleSheetUri, 
                                  bool shouldAllowUserToEditData)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(styleSheetUri))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(
                               "styleSheetUri", 
                               "styleSheetUri can not be null");
            }

            styleSheetPath = styleSheetUri;
            fillable = shouldAllowUserToEditData;
        }

        public void Transform(Stream inputXml, Stream transformedXml)
        {
            if (inputXml == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(
                                    "inputXml", 
                                    "Input xml can not be null.");
            }

            if (transformedXml == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullExceptio(
                                    "transformedStream", 
                                    "TransformedStream can not be null.");
            }

            XslCompiledTransform transformer = new XslCompiledTransform();

            XsltSettings xsltSettings = new XsltSettings();
            xsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction = true;

            XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();

            XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            readerSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;

            try
            {
                transformer.Load(styleSheetPath, xsltSettings, resolver);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format(
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       "Error while loding & compiling the Xsl file, the system returned {0}", 
                        ex.Message));
            }

            XmlReader inputXmlReader;
            try
            {
                inputXmlReader = XmlReader.Create(inputXml, readerSettings);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Error loading the XML file, the system returned {0}", ex.Message));
            }

            // do the transform              
            try
            {
                transformer.Transform(
                                   inputXmlReader, 
                                   xsltArguments, 
                                   transformedXml);
                transformedXml.Position = 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Error in transforming the XML file and XSL file, the system returned {0}", ex.Message));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use Rhino Mocks to unit test that class. Simply create a new test and send some hard coded xml to the method and a MemoryStream. You can assert on the data written to the MemoryStream, after calling the Transform-method.

Maybe you could explain why you would like to use Rhino Mocks to test that method?

Comment: Well we wehere using Rhino mocks everywhere thats why just want be consistant

Comment: I don't suggest that you use some other kind of technology to write your test. I usually don't mock out references to .NET types, unless they access the disc, network, database or other stuff that don't really apply for a unit test. But it is probably a matter of taste :) Good luck with your test.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I can see is that stream paremeters are not abstracted by an interface

```
void Transform(Stream inputXml, Stream transformedXml);
```

But anyway RhinoMocks allows mocking of the abstract classes using `PartialMock` feature.

So test stub would like: (pseudo code)

```cs
var transformer = new XmlToFOTransformer(
                                   styleSheetUri, 
                                   shouldAllowUserToEditData);

// Arrange
var inputXmlStreamMock = mockRepository.PartialMock<Stream>(ctor args);
var transformedXmlStreamMock = mockRepository.PartialMock<Stream>(ctor args);

// setup expectations
// ...

// Act
transformer.Transform(inputXmlStreamMock, transformedXmlStreamMock );


// Assert
// asserts here
```

See for more details: [Rhino Mocks Partial Mocks](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Partial+Mocks.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Comment: Do you know where can find good articals on Rhino Mocks using the latest framework?

Comment: @user686732 : unfortunately no, only pure online Rhino WIKI... and intrawebs forums like SO ;)